# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error in linux terminal but not visual studio in windows

Tags: c++, linux

I have to create a String class without using any of the C++ string functions. One of the functions needed is += (concatenate). When I run my code in visual studio it works fine, but when I run it in terminal in linux i get the following: *** Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000004013cd ***
Aborted (core dumped).

Here is my code:

```
String & String::operator+=(const String & s)
{
    int tempSize = size + s.size;
    char *temp = new char[tempSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++){
        if(i < size)
            temp[i] = buffer[i];
        else
            temp[i] = s.buffer[i - size];
    }

    delete []buffer;
    buffer = temp;
    size = tempSize;
    return *this;
}
```

Any ideas as to why I get this error in terminal, but not in visual studio on windows?

Here are the functions for my String class:

```
class String
{
private:
    int size;
    char *buffer;

public:
    String();
    String(const String &);
    String(const char *);
    ~String();

    int length();
    String & operator=(const String &);
    String & operator+=(const String &);
    char & operator[](unsigned int);

    friend bool operator==(const String &, const String &);
    friend bool operator<=(const String &, const String &);
    friend bool operator<(const String &, const String &);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const String &);
};
```

And here is the test code:

```
String s1;
assert(s1.length() == 0);

String s2("hi");
assert(s2.length() == 2);

String s3(s2);
assert(s3.length() == 2);
assert(s3[0] == 'h');
assert(s3[1] == 'i');

s1 = s2;
assert(s1 == s2);

s3 = "bye";
assert(s3.length() == 3);
assert(s3[0] == 'b');
assert(s3[1] == 'y');
assert(s3[2] == 'e');

s1 += "re";
cout << s1 << endl;
assert(s1 == "hire");

s1 += "d";
assert(!(s1 == "hire"));

cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you by any chance doing something like `s += s;`?

Comment: Make it easier on yourself and write two separate loops -- the first loop copies the original data, and the second loop adds the data for `s`.  Second, we don't know exactly what state your `String` objects are in when you call this function.  Next time post a program that duplicates the error, not just a single function.

Comment: `Any ideas as to why I get this error in terminal, but not in visual studio on windows?`  You have a bug, regardless of whether it is run in Visual Studio or not.

Comment: We also don't know what operations you performed on the `String` before you called this function and whether there are bugs in these operations. That's why we need to see your `String` class and a `main()` function that shows how you're using the `String` objects.

Comment: Added more information, didnt include all the functions and their code, if needed I can, but it seems like it would be more than needed. In visual studio i have no errors or warnings, I dont doubt I have a bug, but it doesnt come up at all there.

Comment: Without a MVCE, we cannot help you.The problem seems to be in code not shown. There may be many reasons for a program breaks in one environment and not in others. Essentialy it is caused by Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `String s3(s2); ... s1 = s2;`  Your code is calling the copy constructor and assignment operator here.  We have no idea if these are coded correctly since you didn't post them.

Comment: @kyho3 Look at this sample:  http://ideone.com/sGUQsR  It uses your main() function, your `operator+=` function and supplied are correct versions of the functions you failed to post, namely copy constructor and assignment operator.  So given what you posted and what was added, the error cannot be duplicated.